# I want to set color Red,Green,Yellow base on data received

Tags: angular

**Understanding**
lets say i will receive data A. so when A==='High' i want to set color Red and when its 'Normal' i want to set green and when its 'Low' i want to set yellow

**Date i received**

```
{
  "expires_in": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 94,
      "patientID": 40,
      "systolicBloodPressure": "120",
      "smokers": "Yes",
      "lipidProfile": "4.4",
      "lipidProfileStatus": "Normal",
      "spiroRatio": 102.22,
      "spiroStatus": "Normal",
      "diabetes": "No",
      "liver": "0.32",
      "kidney": "53.67",
      "kidneyStatus": "Low",
      "depression": "Normal",
      "anxiety": "Normal",
      "stress": "Normal"
    }
  ],
}
```

**Code that i tried**
here im getting map is not a function.Any alternative way to set color is much appreciated.By the way im new to angular please help.Thanks

```
getClientProfileInfo() {
    //debugger
    this.clientService.getClientProfileInfo(this.clientId).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
        this.clientProfileModel = response.data;  
        this.isPortalActivate = this.clientProfileModel.patientInfo[0].isPortalActivate;
        const userId = this.clientProfileModel.patientInfo[0] && this.clientProfileModel.patientInfo[0].userID;
        this.clientService.updateClientNavigations(this.clientId, userId);
        if (this.clientProfileModel) {
          this.getChatHistory();
        }
        this.clientProfileModel = (response.data || []).map((obj: any) => {
          obj.customColorForLipidProfile = this.setColor(obj.lipidProfileStatus) ;
          obj.customColorForLungsSpiro = this.setColor(obj.spiroStatus) ;
          obj.customColorForLiverStatus = this.setColor(obj.liverStatus);
          obj.customColorForKidney = this.setColor(obj.kidneyStatus) ;
          return obj;
          });
          
      }
    });
  }

  setColor(key) {
    let customColor;
    switch (key) {
      case 'High': {
        customColor = '#ff5454';
        break;
      }
      case 'Normal': {
        customColor = '#fd9b4b';
        break;
      }
      default: {
        // default case is for Low status
        customColor = '#53D8A2';
        break;
      }
    }
    return customColor;
  }
```

**Tried this approach too**
this code only prints the else part i dont know what went wrong

```
  if(this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0]!=undefined && this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0].kidneyStatus === 'Low'){
      this.customColor ='#ff5454';
    }else if(this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0]!=undefined && this.clientProfileModel.patientHealthScores[0].kidneyStatus === 'Normal') {
      this.customColor ='#fd9b4b';
    } else {
      this.customColor ='#53D8A2';
    }
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you edit you questions to include what the expected / actual behaviors are, and if possible a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You mean you want to show it on Html part ? Than you have to call your obj at html part and set css color property from obj. For example <p>Kidney Status: <span [ngStyle]="{'color': obj.customColorForKidney }">...</span> </p>

Comment: above code have one error that says map is not a function

Comment: Can you check if your response.Data has data and it is not undefined ?

Comment: this is the data that i get at my network tap [{patientHealthScoreID: 0, id: 94, patientID: 40, fvc: "45", lipidProfile: "4.4",…}]

Comment: where kidneyStatus key info is coming in your response

Comment: yes its coming all the required data are coming

Comment: enum Color {
  "High" = "#ff5454",
  "Normal" = "#fd9b4b",
  "Low" = "#53D8A2"
}

const high = 'High';

console.log(Color[high])

Comment: I am still not sure what you are looking for. Please clarify your question by asking directly what is the problem, getting error, how you do something or something else. Second which angular version you are using? is there any other error beside map error ? have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask pls to get idea how you can ask better.

Comment: I have solved my issue. By the way thanks for taking time at my issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve `"map is not a function."` error be sure you imported **`map`** function from rxjs. It should be like below:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

If you have imported map function and still you are getting error. Be sure the array that calling map function is not `null` or `undefined`.

If they are all ok and you are still getting error. Call map function in `pipe`

```
this.clientProfileModel = (response.data || []).pipe(
      map((obj: any) => {
      obj.customColorForLipidProfile = this.setColor(obj.lipidProfileStatus) ;
      obj.customColorForLungsSpiro = this.setColor(obj.spiroStatus) ;
      obj.customColorForLiverStatus = this.setColor(obj.liverStatus);
      obj.customColorForKidney = this.setColor(obj.kidneyStatus) ;
      return obj;
      })
   );
```

Comment: I updown because the **map** is a map of an **array** not about rxjs/operator, I feel that the response can confussed.

Comment: @Eliseo I am really not sure the user want to use array map here. you can see in  the code it is handling an http call and subscribe to response. I think we can assume it is rxjs map method.  or even it is not it will be better choice. Isn't it?

Comment: See that the map is about "response.data". You can use `this.clientService.getClientProfileInfo(this.clientId).pipe(map(response=>...)).subscribe(responseModified)` (here is a rxjs operator because getClientProfile return an observable) or `this.clientService.getClientProfileInfo(this.clientId).subscribe((response:any[])=>response.map(...))` (here is a map of the array because the response is an array).